# How to parse a data file to extract specific data and format for other use?

Tags: text-processing, grep, regular-expression

Given a data file which contains various content, I would like to first ignore any line that does not start with an IP address, then output the IP address followed by any string found in the braces that does not contain an `=` sign.  Any given line may have one or multiple strings.

For example:

INPUT:

```
junk12  
junk34  
198.0.12.20 [ joker penguin character=villian ] blah  
198.0.13.20 [ super_man bat_man character=hero ] blah  
198.0.14.20 [ lois_lane character=damsel ] blah  
junk56  
junk78
```

OUTPUT:

```
198.0.12.20 joker  
198.0.12.20 penguin  
198.0.13.20 super_man  
198.0.13.20 bat_man  
198.0.14.20 lois_lane
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be many ways of doing this, but in `awk` we can do something like

```
awk 'gsub(/^[0-9.]+ \[ /,$1 " ") { a=2; while (a<=NR && $a != "]") { if ($a !~ /=/) {print $1 " " $a } ; a++ } }'
```

Let's break this down into something more readable:

```
gsub(/^[0-9.]+ \[ /,$1 " ") { .... }
```

This will match lines that begin with numbers and dots, followed by a space and a `[`.  So it will match `10.20.30.40 [` but won't match `junk23`.  It will replace it with the first field and then run the stuff inside the `{...}`.

So a line like

```
198.0.12.20 [ joker penguin character=villian ] blah
```

will enter that section looking like

```
198.0.12.20 joker penguin character=villian ] blah
```

Now the middle part, which might be easier to understand if we write it on multiple lines:

```
a=2;
while (a<=NR && $a != "]")
{
  if ($a !~ /=/) {print $1 " " $a }
  a++;
}
```

So we start at the 2nd field ("joker" in this case) and continue on until we run out of words or we see the `]`.  For each word we find, if it doesn't contain an `=` then we print the first field (the IP address) and the word.

The results:

```
198.0.12.20 joker
198.0.12.20 penguin
198.0.13.20 super_man
198.0.13.20 bat_man
198.0.14.20 lois_lane
```

(There's probably better ways of doing this!)

Comment: To make this more robust, how could whitespace before and after the IP address be ignored?  There will always be a new line before the IP address, however, there might be 0-5 spaces before as well.  Same situation in between the IP address and the [.

Comment: Modify the `gsub()` search to better match the pattern; eg `/^ *[0-9.]+ +\[ /` which allow zero or more spaces before the IP address and one or more spaces after it.

Comment: This worked great.  I will give you the checkmark as soon as my rep is 15+.